# Subtracting digits from an integer right to left

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
void printDigit(int n) 
{ 
    int d; 
    int temp;
    int temp2;
    if (n == 0) { 
        return; 
    } 
    d = n % 10; 
    printf("%d ", d);
    printDigit(n / 10); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 755545; 
  
    printDigit(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

So I need to subtract each digit with the next one right to left, so for example 5-4=1, 4-5=-1 and then print them like xxxx -1 1 . I tried something like getting a temp int in there but I need it changed every recursion.

Edit: for the input number 755545 the output should be -2 0 0 -1 1.

Comment: Show sample input, expected output, and actual output. Also, if you want a variable to persist among recursions, simply pass it from one recursion to another.

Comment: @underscore_d I added the expected output, my actual output right now is just printing those digits right to left, because whatever I tried it didn't compile and didn't make much sense.

Comment: It's worth checking if your `int` is capable of storing `755545`, some implementations limit the the size of `int` to 2 bytes. Use `sizeof(int)` to check the number of bytes.

Comment: what are ```temp``` and ```temp2``` used for?

Comment: @isragram that was my original idea to store the digits in them, but it didn't work.

Comment: "_whatever I tried it didn't compile and didn't make much sense_" - so show what you tried and quote the errors that stopped it compiling.

Comment: Its easy just wait 10 mins I'll give you the code

Comment: Right to left or left to right ? ‘755545 the output should be -2 0 0 -1 1’  you are going from left to right and doing right-left on digits. If you want to print the last result first, invert printf and printDigit()

Comment: @underscore_d I'm learning C, I didn't have much of an idea, I set my temp=n%10; and I tried putting temp2=n%10 but after the recursion, at the end all I get are 0s.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, exactly the printing is left to right, but the subtracting is right-left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete function

```
int subDigits(int number){
    if(number>0){
        int temp = number;
        temp = temp / 10;
        digits(number/10);
        if(temp>0) {
            cout << number % 10 - temp % 10 << " ";
        }
    }
}




int main() {
    subDigits(1562);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it now, I tried something similiar but the order was wrong,

Comment: Yes, in recursive functions order matters the most

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temporary variable for storing the previous digit. The expression `(n / 10) % 10` will give you the previous digit. The `if(n / 10 == 0)` makes sure that the recursion ends one depth early making the expression `(n / 10) % 10` always work.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
void print_digit(int n)
{
    if(n / 10 == 0) return;
    print_digit(n / 10);
    printf("%d ", (n % 10) - (n / 10 % 10));
    
}

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 755545; 
    print_digit(n);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Let's take the number `755545`, the exit statement is encountered when the value `75` is passed. Here's how the flow goes:

```
755545
|- 75554
 |- 7555
  |- 755
   |- 75
     print (75 % 10) - (75 / 10 % 10) = 5 - 7 =      -2
  |- print (755 % 10) - (755 / 10 % 10) = 5 - 5 =     0
 |- print ( 7555 % 10) - (7555 / 10 % 10) = 5 - 5 =   0
|- print (75554 % 10) - (75554 / 10 % 10) = 4 - 5 =  -1
print (755545 % 10) - (755545 / 10 % 10) = 5 - 4 =    1
```

Comment: Yes, I get it now, thank you! I couldn't figure the (n / 10) % 10 by myself, cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. I've also edited my answer to demonstrate the flow. Hope it helps :)